# mbed receive String from pc

Tags: serial-port, mbed

I am learning mbed, and doing some examples. My code is to send a random string "ccc" from my pc to microcontroller LPCXpresso.

```
enter code here
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut myled(LED1);
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

int main() {
    char c;
    char buffer[128];
    myled = 1;

    pc.gets(buffer, 4);

    pc.printf("I got '%s'\n", buffer);
    if(buffer == 'ccc'){
       myled = 0;
    }    
}
```

I enter 'ccc', and the printf does return the message: I got 'ccc'. However, in the if statement, if I use (buffer == 'ccc'), I see the error message: Error: Operand types are incompatible ("char *" and "int") in "main.cpp". If i use (buffer == "ccc") my led does not light up as expected since I know for sure the buffer is ccc.

How could I make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare strings like that in C/C++. Use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). E.g.:

```
if (strcmp(buffer, "ccc") == 0) {
```